# Raspberry PI to AVR attiny26 via SPI - three wire mode, garbled output

Tags: avr, spi, garbage, attiny

I have Raspberry PI 3 connected via SPI to AVR Attiny26, which in turn has a LCD connected to it. I am trying to get the SPI running,

Now, the issue is that when I set up the AVR for two wire mode and don't configure pull-up on PB1 (MISO commented out):

```
USICR = (1<<USIOIE)|(1<<USIWM1)|(1<<USICS1); // Enable USI interrupt - USIOIE=1
                                             // Three wire mode USIWM1=0, USIWM0=1
                                             // Two wire mode USIWM1=1, USIWM0=0
                                             // External clock USICS1=1

//PORTB |= (1<<SPI_MISO);                    // Enable pull-ups on SPI port

DDRB = 0b01001010;                           /* Set PORTB bits: 7-4 as input
                                                -- PB7 - Pushbutton (KEY1)/RESET
                                                -- PB6 - Pushbutton (KEY2)/INT0
                                                -- PB5 - ADC8 (T2)
                                                -- PB4 - ADC7 (T1)
                                                -- PB3 - PUMP               
                                                -- PB2 - SCK - 0 = external clock (input)
                                                -- PB1 - MISO (output)
                                                -- PB0 - MOSI (input) -  */


ISR(USI_OVF_vect) {

    disp[counter++] = USIDR;
    if(counter==16) 
        counter = 0;

    USISR |= (1<<USIOIF);
}
```

I get the string transfered and printed on the LCD.

However, when I change the AVR to work in three wire mode and/or enable PB1 pull-up, all I get is garbage. Neither the received characters match the ones sent, nor does their count.

Raspberry is the master here, providing all the clocking, the setup there is always the same (default, three wire mode) and the clock is reasonably slow.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int res = bcm2835_init();
    printf("BCM2835 Init() = %d\n", res);

    res = bcm2835_spi_begin();
    printf("BCM2835 Begin() = %d\n", res);

    bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_65536);

    char data[16];
    sprintf(data,"%s","<--Some data-->");
    int len = strlen(data);

    printf("Sent: %s\n", data);
    bcm2835_spi_writenb(data, len);
    exit(0);
}
```

Same results with spidev_test program using ioctl, so does not seem related to the library/Pi's program.

On top, what is puzzling me is that when I disconnect the wire from PB1 (MISO), I immediately start receiving garbage from Pi. As if Pi's SPI immediately starts clocking when PB1/MISO goes afloat.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am hoping that you have taken care of 1 - selecting alternate function 2 - selecting proper SPI mode as AVR supports MODE - 0 and MODE - 1 in three wire mode. So from Pi, I am hoping that you have chosen mode 0 or mode 1 in the spi controller. Also I am hoping you have selected proper AF in Pi too. If all of these are taken care of then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I looked at the code again, ran some experiments, but no change. As per code in the original post:  - USICS1=1 means external clock, positive edge  - Pi is in default SPI mode (mode 0, CPOL=0, CPHA=0).  Both are in line with the timing diagram in attiny's manual, which says that DI should be sampled well after it has been set up.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Also I hope you are changing WM1 to 0 and WM0 to 1 for three-wire mode.

Comment: Yes, that is the part I am changing. As said, the moment I enable pull-up on PB1 or set USIWM0 for three-wire mode, I don't receive anything meaningful.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share the init code for three-wire mode?

Comment: As per comments in the code above, the only difference is that USIWM0=1 instead of USIWM1. Optionally, PORTB pull-up, commented out in the example above, would be switched on. Each of these changes results in garbled reception, regardless of whether they are done independently of each other or together. BTW, at this stage I am not interested in receiving data from AVR, so the DO/MISO settings are irrelevant.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to AVR pins pull-up configuration. In two wire mode, pull-ups on SCL/SDA are disabled. The Pi seems to provide these by default, which could explain why two-wire mode works, whereas three wire does not (pull-ups provided on both sides). However, I am having difficulties decyphering/forcing the settings for the three wire mode. Still not there, but possibly on track...

Comment: Thanks sharing the update. It will be a learning. But I am confused that why for SPI, you need Pull ups. For I2C its required.

Answer (score 0):

Regretfully, I have to say that this one goes into the RTFM category.

After some reserch I found that Pi GPIO works with +3.3V. The Attiny was set to use+ 5V. After rewiring the AVR to work with 3.3V as well, everything seems to be working.

The reason why it worked in two wire mode is the absence of AVR's pull-up resistors (external required), which allowed Pi to use its own and drive the AVR pins in the range acceptable to both Pi and AVR. Enabling pull-ups on AVR would drive Pi's GPIO over the limit. Apparently no damage done, only unpredictable and hard to explain behavior.